# How to enable vertical scroll bar in windows app?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, scrollbar

I added a TextBlock that have more text than visible.  Now even thought I try to set every single properties about Scrollbars to be enabled or visible, I have none in the Simulator or even running the app from the START SCREEN.  I also tried to add my TextBlock in a ScrollViewer, no luck !

I'm using HTML + Javascript

Comment: you can set a some maxheight for your control on which you are applying scrollviewer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `overflow` property of CSS.